# String Reflowing in ios webview

Tags: ios, string, uiwebview

I have a long text that I want to reflow and display in a uiwebview with disabled scrolling. I tried using this code:

```
-(NSInteger)lengthOfString:(NSString *)str 
          thatFitsIntoView:(UIView *)displayView 
                  withFont:(UIFont *)font
{
      CGSize textSize = [str sizeWithFont:font 
                        constrainedToSize:displayView.frame.size 
                            lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];


 NSInteger lengthThatFits;
 CGFloat display = 414.000000;
 NSLog(@"%f -%f",displayView.frame.size.width,textSize.height);
 if (textSize.height > displayView.frame.size.width)
 {
      lengthThatFits = str.length * display / textSize.height;
 } 
 else 
 {
      lengthThatFits = str.length;
 }
 return lengthThatFits;
```

}

To check what part of the string will fit in a single view, but still gives me a string length more than what will fit to a webview. Is there any way to split a string to fit a single view?

Comment: And what happened?  Or what are you asking?

Comment: it still gives me a length more than the capacity of a view

Comment: If lengthThatFits is longer than the view, you need to set contentSize of the view to be that big, then it will be able to scroll.

Comment: I want to create an ebook reading app, so I want to creat a uiview without scrolling and would reflow the content.